# How to enter single-user mode in Ubuntu 13.04 to install e4rat?

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP dv6, and I've been going through the usual ritual of setting up Bumblebee etc. Since Jupiter is no longer supported, I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/285681/172760) to install TLP. I also followed the instructions in the Update section of the answer, to add **PowerSavingTweaks for Intel Graphics** by editing `/etc/default/grub` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1"
```

I then got down to installing e4rat, following the procedure described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/). I managed to successfully run `e4rat-collect`, but I can't complete the rest of the procedure (the `e4rat-realloc` portion), since I am unable to boot into the single-user mode. The steps I followed are the same as those mentioned in the HTG article. However, the screen goes black, some stuff gets loaded up, the screen gets cleared and then I see a message saying `kvm: diabled by bios` with the cursor blinking below it.

I have waited for more than an hour, tried `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, but all to no avail. I have also tried moving `single` around in that line - before `quiet splash`, after `quiet splash`, at the end of the line (after `vthandoff`). I have even tried deleting the Power Saving Tweak code and replacing it with `single`, but I get the same result every time. Interestingly, before I started this entire procedure, I had tried to boot into single-user mode and it had worked back then.

Comment: When you boot to single user mode, edit the grub line, use (add) the options "nomodeset", do not use (remove) "quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: You meant `nomodeset single`? I tried out what you said but it didn't work.